# Why am I able to get text from one XML node but not its siblings?

Tags: xml, asp-classic, vbscript, xmldom

Why am I able to get text from one XML node but not its siblings? I must be doing something wrong now, I actually  had it working at one point but I was choosing the wrong sibling at the time. This code below returns AND writes the strRespone to my source code. But I get error '' on the next one.

Error:
Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01a8'

Object required

/preview.asp, line 905 ( Line: strAuthCode = strBMLAuthCode.text )

Code:

```
Dim NodeList, Node, SubNode
Set NodeList = xmlDom.documentElement.selectNodes("onlineresponse/authorizationresponse")

Set strBMLResponse = xmlDom.SelectSingleNode("//response")
    strResponse = strBMLResponse.text
    Response.Write "<!--strResponse: " & strResponse & "-->"


If strResponse = "000" Then '//SUCCESS!!
    Set strBMLAuthCode = xmlDom.SelectSingleNode("//id")
        strAuthCode = strBMLAuthCode.text
        Response.Write "strAuthCode: " & strAuthCode & "<br>"


    Set strBMLAcctNum = xmlDom.SelectSingleNode("//number")
        strAcctNum = strBMLAcctNum.text
        Response.Write "strAcctNum: " & strAcctNum & "<br>"
        strCCNum = strAcctNum

Else ' if strResponse <> '000'...
```

NO XML:
I figured it out.. taking the xml down as a precaution for our security.

Thanks!

EDIT:
I will post the answer soon.

Comment: IS it possible it is not working correctly because the <?xml version="1.0"?> element is missing?

Answer (score 2):

Your Hungarian notation is ghastly. You use a "str" prefix for things that are both strings and not strings, i.e. strBMLResponse is not a string! Consider renaming your values as follows:

```
Dim xmlResponse
Set xmlResponse = xmlDom.SelectSingleNode("//response")
Dim strResponse
strResponse = xmlResponse.text
```

Secondly, you have no error checking, i.e. your code always assumes the Set always assigns a valid object. But, in practice there could be scenarios where `Nothing` is returned, i.e.

```
If strResponse = "000" Then
    Dim xmlAuthCode
    Set xmlAuthCode = xmlDom.SelectSingleNode("//litletxnid")
    If Not (xmlAuthCode is Nothing) Then
        Dim strAuthCode
        strAuthCode = xmlAuthCode.text
        Rem ...
    End If
End If
```

I did some checking on the XML you supplied and the code you supplied and the error is not reproducible, so, I'll assume that there is insufficient information. i.e. I'm guessing the contents of the xmlDom doesn't actually contain an "litletxnid" node. You'll need to do some additional checking to confirm or deny that situation.

EDIT:

Thanks for your additional information. As mentioned earlier I'm having troubles reproducing the problem with the information supplied. This means more troubleshooting is needed particularly with a deep dive analysis on the `litletxnid` node. You have other ways to get to it, for example:

```
Dim xmlAuthCode
Set xmlAuthCode = xmlDom.documentElement.firstChild.firstChild
Rem You can add debugging here like view xmlAuthCode.xml
```

Comment: Thank you for the critique on the variable names. I will start there.

Comment: HI, I added more updates to my original question showing how I am loading the XML Response..

Comment: The FULL xmmResponse is there, because I write it out to my source, I can see what is coming back from the web service.